# Access is denied. How to resolve problems with docker cp due to permission on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, docker

I'm trying to copy files from my container to the host using:

```
docker cp aa88c93d0710:/home/app/env/ C:\Users\MY_USERNAME\OneDrive\Desktop\app\backend\
```

yielding the following error message:
`open C:\Users\MY_USERNAME\OneDrive\Desktop\app\backend\Lib\site-packages\Flask-1.1.2.dist-info\entry_points.txt: Access is denied.`

However, this is working fine:
`docker cp aa88c93d0710:/home/app/env/ C:\`

So I figure that the error is due to docker lacking some permissions on Windows 10? How to resolve this? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I finally fixed this by temporarily disabling **Admin Approval Mode** in Windows 10:

1. Console `secpol.msc`
2. Navigate to `Security Settings` > `Local Policies` > `Security Options`
3. Edit properties of `User Account Control: Run all administrators in Admin Approval Mode.` and set to `disabled`.

Now, `docker cp` will copy files from the container to the host as expected, although I'm not happy with the solution.